# Как удалить черновик ответа?

Tags: поддержка, ответы

Начал писать ответ, отвлекся, когда вернулся необходимость в продолжении написания ответа отпала - автор решил свою проблему. При этом сохраненный черновик ответа продолжает висеть в поле ввода. Как его удалить?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нажмите малозаметную ссылку «отменить» под полем редактирования ответа, сохранённое содержимое будет удалено.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Надо кнопку назвать "отменить и удалить черновик". А то мне кажется я уже кому-то отвечал раньше как этот черновик удалить, а теперь сам забыл.

Comment: @alexolut наверняка в оригинале "discard".

Comment: Так и [есть](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267179?key=70f68bb2f748b85de6526bfe236ea1e9)