# Вопрос уже задан, но всё ещё сохранён

Tags: дефект, ask-question-wizard

При открытии страницы [Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) на ней отображается ранее написанное содержимое, даже если вопрос [уже был задан](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1093152/178988). Считаю что после того, как вопрос опубликован на сайте, его разметку надо убирать из сохранений и открывать пустое окно. Особенно при том, что чистить надо все 3 поля - заголовок, тело вопроса и метки.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Вряд ли это связано с визардом. Я нечто подобное и раньше наблюдал, может быть как-то связано с тем, что начал писать на одной устройстве, закончил на другом и т.п.

Comment: 3 поля, наверное, всё же чистить не надо. Есть кнопка "Удалить черновик". Аналог [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3794/176217).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, во-первых, конкретно этот вопрос я писал за один раз на одном устройстве, а черновик встретил на другом, во-вторых, это было вчера на всех сайтах - и на основном, и на мете, и на enSO. Хотя сегодня вроде уже не воспроизводится. Кнопку удалить я во-первых не видел, во-вторых, к ней надо скроллить. Ну и выгоды от черновика никакой - он же уже не черновик, а вполне опубликованный вопрос, а постинг дубликатов нам поощрять не надо.